# Difference between there will be no and there won't be

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

Is there the difference between 'there will be no' and 'there won't be'? Or are they the same?

The following are two examples to compare:

> - I'm afraid **there will be no** time to see Granny.
> - I'm afraid **there won't be** time to see Granny.

Comment: I think both are ok, though the second one would be better as "I'm afraid there won't be **any** time to see Granny.